# Computing the successive minima of the following lattice in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let us define the lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by the matrix
$$
\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
    A & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & A & 0 & 0 \\
    \gamma_1 & \gamma_2 & B & 0 \\
    \gamma_{2} & \gamma_{3} & 0 & B  
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where all the entries are real numbers. I was wondering is it possible to compute the successive minima just knowing that the lattice has this shape? Any comments/references/suggestions would be appreciated!